# MySQL. Counting just a part of my column value

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a question relating tables in MySQL. To understand this better I'd rather show you. I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tip_masina` (
  `id_tip` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `marca` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `pret` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_tip`),
  UNIQUE KEY `marca` (`marca`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=16 ;


INSERT INTO `tip_masina` (`id_tip`, `marca`, `pret`) VALUES
(1, 'Chevrolet Impala', 8000),
(2, 'Chevrolet Camaro', 10000),
(3, 'Chevrolet Tahoe', 13000),
(4, 'Chevrolet Suburban', 12500),
(5, 'Chevrolet Cobalt', 4000),
(6, 'Dodge Charger', 14000),
(7, 'Dodge Avenger', 9000),
(8, 'Dodge Challenger', 6500),
(9, 'Dodge Dart', 3500),
(10, 'Dodge Durango', 3000),
(11, 'Ford Mustang', 7500),
(12, 'Ford Crown Victoria', 5000),
(13, 'Ford Focus', 4300),
(14, 'Ford Fiesta', 3700),
(15, 'Ford Escort', 1000);
```

What I want out of this table is to display the vehicle type and the number of vehicles, like:

```
marca      |  no_of_vehicles
Chevrolet          5
Dodge              5
Ford               5
```

Is there any way to do this without splitting the column marca in two columns?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an easy way, using `substring_index()`:

```
select substring_index(marca, ' ', 1) as marca, count(*)
from tip_masina
group by substring_index(marca, ' ', 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

It might be better to split 'marca' into two columns so that it would be easier to find what you want. You won't need any special functions then (as e.g. substring_index).

EDIT:
You can use following code:

EDIT2: 
Now it works (tested on mysql workbench with your queries creating table):

```
START TRANSACTION;
ALTER TABLE tip_masina ADD model VARCHAR(60) AFTER marca;
ALTER TABLE tip_masina CHANGE marca company VARCHAR(60);
UPDATE tip_masina SET model = SUBSTRING_INDEX(company, ' ', -1);
ALTER TABLE tip_masina DROP INDEX marca;
UPDATE tip_masina SET company = SUBSTRING_INDEX(company, ' ', 1);
SELECT * FROM tip_masina;
```

Comment: Yeah, I have way more values than I posted in that question. Next time I will be more careful and think the DB through and not hit these problems.

Comment: I added a new solution for you. Now you can keep your cars in two separate columns.